# Stuck on 'Ads API Access Level:development'

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I try to have an app that can pause/resume my adset (accounts owned by myself).

I get no error message(or anything) output when requesting this

```
$adset = new AdSet($adsetid);
$adset->campaign_status = AdSet::STATUS_ACTIVE;
try{
  $adset->updateSelf();
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody(), true);
    var_dump($response);
}
```

But I see that the adset status did not change.

Now, I do see that the Marketing API, Settings section shows me that the API access Level is development and the app doesn't have Ads management standard access.

[image: no standard access]

When I check permissions at App review > Permissions and features it shows 'Standard access' and 'ready to use'. (however not 'Active')

[image: permissions]

And at the same time my request count and error rate in the past 30 days are acceptable.
I don't understand what is missing to make it work. Can anyone help me out?

[image: callcount and error rate]

Comment: _“I get no error message(or anything)”_ - you are only catching exceptions of a specific type there - are you sure that’s the only type of exception this could possibly ever throw? Start by adding a catch block that catches any generic exception, and see what you get then.

Comment: Making the analog request manually in Graph API Explorer could maybe also shed some light.

Comment: It returns me this, while the actual status did not change when verifying in ads manager.
{
    "success": true
}

It just feels like my access have to get validated/get permissions right for it to get in some production mode. But don't know what task I need to complete to get it going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I have shown in my question was based on the code I copied from the Facebook marketing API documentation.

Strangely when I simulated my request using the Graph API Explorer and hit the "Get code" button it will suggest you a different code.

When I used that code instead of the code of the marketing API docs it did seem to work just as expected.
This code worked as opposed to the code from the docs:

```
$adsetid = "YOUR ADSET ID";
$access_token = "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN";
try {
  $response = $fb->post(
    '/'.$adsetid,
    array (
      'fields' => 'status',
      'status' => 'ACTIVE'
    ),
    $access_token
  );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```